# How to implement Regex in AMP

Tags: amp-html

How to implement Regex in AMP if regex validate  button remove disabled in AMP button tag

```
<input type="button" on="tap:my-lightbox" class="btn" value="Select Package" id="domain_invalid_button" disabled="disabled">
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

1. Use [amp-form's built in validation mechanism](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-form/#custom-validations) which also supports patterns.
2. Use amp-script to implement your own validation using JavaScript:

This is how it would work with amp-script:

```
<amp-script layout="container" script="form-validation-script" class="amp-script-sample" sandbox="allow-forms">
  <input id="validated-input" placeholder="Only upper case letters allowed...">
  <button id="validated-input-submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</amp-script>

<script id="form-validation-script" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
  const submitButton = document.querySelector('#validated-input-submit');
  const validatedInput = document.querySelector('#validated-input');
  validatedInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const isValid = /^[A-Z]+$/.test(validatedInput.value);
    if (isValid) {
      submitButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
      submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', '');
    }
  });
</script>
```

Note: [inline amp-script requires a CSP script hash](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-script/#load-javascript-from-a-local-element) to work.